# Pages not listed in Vue Material md-tabs throw a "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null"

Tags: vue-material

I'm using Vue Material, and their `md-tabs` component to manage the application tabs (Home, Profile ...).

I'd like to create a `/404` page, which obviously **cannot be a tab** :)

To do so I simply add a /404 entry to the router:

```js
const routes = [
  { path: '/home', name: 'Home', component: Home },
  { path: '/profile', name: 'Profile', component: Profile },
  { path: '/404', name: '404', component: NotFound },
  { path: '*', redirect: '/404' },
];
```

It works, but on the /404 page I get the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null
>       at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue-material/dist/vue-material.js:14093)

The error disappears whan adding an `md-tab` for the `/404`, which is not a solution XD

```html
<md-tabs md-sync-route class="md-primary">
  <md-tab id="tab-home" md-label="Home" to="/home"></md-tab>
  <md-tab id="tab-profile" md-label="Profile" to="/profile"></md-tab>
  <md-tab id="tab-404" md-label="404" to="/404"></md-tab>
</md-tabs>
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Thank you !

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: Unfortunately no I haven't. I finally stopped to use vue material ^^

Comment: @Playmor what did you use instead of vue material?

Comment: For now raw vue 3

Answer (score 0):

This should fix your issue:

```
<md-tabs router-link>
  <md-tab md-label="Foo" to="/foo">foo</md-tab>
  <md-tab md-label="Bar" to="/bar">bar</md-tab>
</md-tabs>
```